# Handling runtime exception in Play 2.0 app

Tags: scala, exception, playframework

In my Play 2.0 app, I am calling a Java API which depends on certain environment variables being set to work properly. However, this can only be checked at runtime and what I would like to do is to throw a meaningful error message at the start of the application but unsure how to handle it. A possible approach is to use require like

```
object TemplatesController extends Controller {
  val driver = setFromEnvVars //returns None or Some(blah)
  require(!driver.isEmpty)

  def index = Action {
    Ok("Wheee")
  }
  ...
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that I get a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` and stack trace (in dev mode) without the ability to display a meaningful error message. Anyone knows a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `object Global extends GlobalSettings` which gets called automatically during startup.  See the [API Docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings)

Comment: Already tried that but either way, I am not able to return a meaningful error message.